# Failure on boot of headless Ubuntu 16.04 LTS server

Tags: boot, server

So I seem to be running into a strange problem. I have attached pictures taken very clumsily from my phone (sorry!) to show the boot screen hang. Its strange because its not consistent. Right now the server is running fine but usually it does not and will lock up on boot. Then I have to physically turn it off by holding down the power button.

Given the screenshots I suspected maybe HDD failure so I ran long tests on each of the HDDs (including the primary boot drive - an ADATA SSD). All came back fine with no errors (there are 5 x 4TB + 1 x 2TB and 1SSD in there).

Some help on thoughts would be good. See the boot screenshots below. It usually locks up either on:

- Reached target sound card
- Reached target local file systems
- And just the once it got past that and it got stuck on a start job....(pic below)

[image]

[image]

Comment: The last message in the second picture shows that the system is waiting for a disk to come online.

Comment: Hi @AlexP so I haven't been able to reproduce that error and didn't take a good enough pic to get the ID. Any suggestions?

Comment: check (change?) cables, connectors, check board(s) for heat damage, etc.  (ie. i'm thinking failing-component due inconsistency)

Comment: The main boot drives runs off of a PCIE Sata card. Maybe that's going.